# jquery fullcalendar: show only two weeks of a month in the page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am new to JQuery [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). I need to show only two weeks of a month in the page (I am using ASP.NET MVC framework).

Can I show only two weeks instead of full month?

Answer (score 2):

Check this page: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/

Scroll down to view object. There are two properties -

**Start**: Date

The Date of the first visible day of the view. In month-view, this value is often before the 1st day of the month, because most months do not begin on a Monday.
In week and day views, this value will always be the same as start.

**End**: Date
The Date of the day after the last visible day (because it is exclusive like end).